# Why does multithreaded file transfer improve performance?

Tags: performance, multithreading, hardware

**RichCopy**, a better-than-robocopy-with-GUI tool from Microsoft, seems to be the current tool of choice for copying files. One of it's main features, hightlighted in the [TechNet article presenting the tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog), is that it *copies multiple files in parallel*. In its default setting, three files are copied simultaneously, which you can see nicely in the GUI: [Progress: xx% of file A, yy% of file B, ...]. There are a lot of [blog](http://www.labnol.org/software/richcopy-file-copying-tool-for-windows/8035/) [entries](http://lifehacker.com/5180622/richcopy-enhances-windows-file-copying-with-advanced-rules) around praising this tool and claiming that this speeds up the copying process.

My question is: **Why does this technique improve performance?** As far as I know, when copying files on modern computer systems, the HDD is the bottleneck, not the CPU or the network. My assumption would be that copying multiple files at once makes the whole process *slower*, since the HDD needs to jump back and forth between different files rather than just sequentially streaming one file. Since RichCopy *is* faster, there must be some mistake in my assumptions...

Comment: PS: I have long thought whether StackOverflow (it's about a programming technique) or SuperUser (it's about using a tool) is the right place for this. I've decided on StackOverflow, since I'm interested in the design decisions of the tool, not in its usage.

Comment: Remember that even on very high bandwidth links (gigabit +), latency is more than zero

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tool is making use improvements in hardware which can optimise multiple read and write requests much better.

When copying one file at a time the hardware isn't going to know that the block of data that currently is passing under the read head (or near by) will be needed of a subsquent read since the software hasn't queued that request yet.

A single file copy these days is not very taxing task for modern disk sub-systems.  By giving these hardware systems more work to do at once the tool is leveraging its improved optimising features.

Answer (score 5):

A naive "copy multiple files" application will copy one file, then wait for that to complete before copying the next one.

This will mean that an individual file CANNOT be copied faster than the network latency, even if it is empty (0 bytes). Because it probably does several file server calls, (open,write,close), this may be several x the latency.

To efficiently copy files, you want to have a server and client which use a sane protocol which has pipelining; that's to say - the client does NOT wait for the first file to be saved before sending the next, and indeed, several or many files may be "on the wire" at once.

Of course to do that would require a custom server not a SMB (or similar) file server. For example, rsync does this and is very good at copying large numbers of files despite being single threaded.

So my guess is that the multithreading helps because it is a work-around for the fact that the server doesn't support pipelining on a single session.

A single-threaded implementation which used a sensible protocol would be best in my opinion.

Comment: Microsoft's file protocols transfer are very poorly 'designed'.
Their implementations are still worse. My evidence of this is that SAMBA will outperform Windows on the same hardware.
 In parallel the copy delays caused by waiting for acknowledgments are mitigated by copying other files in the "dead time."

Comment: My point was not that the protocol is badly designed; it's that its design doesn't lend itself to this particular use case.

The protocol design is sufficient to implement the requirement to provide transparent remote file access; it just doesn't work too well for copying many small files over a link with latency - you need something else for that.

Answer (score 3):

It's a network tool, so the bottleneck is the network, not the HDD. Up to a (low) point you can get more throughput out of a TCP link by using a few connections in parallel. This (a) parallelizes the TCP handshakes; (b) can make better use of the bandwidth-delay product if that is high; and (c) doesn't make one arbitrarily slow connection the critical path if for some reason it encounters a high RTT or failure rate.

Another way to do (b) is to use an enormous TCP socket receive buffer but that's not always convenient.

Several of the other answers about HDD are incorrect. Practically any HDD will do some read-ahead on the assumption of sequential access, and any intelligent OS cache will also do that.

Answer (score 1):

My gues is that the hdd read write heads spend most of their time idle and wait for the correct memory block of the disk to apear under them, the more memory being copied means less time in idle and most modern disk schedulers should take care of the jumping (for a low number of files/fragments)

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, when copying files on modern computer systems, the HDD is the bottleneck, not the CPU or the network.

I think those assumptions are overly simplistic.

First, while LANs run at 100Mb / 1Gbit.  Long haul networks have a maximum data rate that is less than the max rate of the slowest link.

Second, the effective throughput of TCP/IP stream over the internet is often dominated by the time taken to round-trip messages and acknowledgments.  For example, I have a 8+Mbit link, but my data rate on downloads is rarely above 1-2Mbits per second when I'm downloading from the USA.  So if you can run multiple streams in parallel one stream can be waiting for an acknowledgment while another is pumping packets.  (But if you try to send too much, you start getting congestion, timeouts, back-off and lower overall transfer rates.)

Finally, operating systems are good at doing a variety of I/O tasks in parallel with other work.  If you are downloading 2 or more files in parallel, the O/S may be reading / processing network packets for one download and writing to disc for another one ... at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Over long distances, networks can write much faster than they can read.  With multithreading, having additional "readers" means the data can be transmitted more efficiently and not bogged down in buffers.